# Python: Check if number at specific position is larger?

Tags: python, find, line

i have a very large file, which can not be opened by kind of texteditor or something. 
And i need to Check if (1) the line starts with a specific string and (2) if a number at a specific position (col 148 (3 digits)) is smaller than a predefined number. This complete line should be printed then

so i tried the following code. but it doesnt work.

```
fobj = open("test2.txt")
for line in fobj:
    if (line.startswith("ABS")) and (fp.seek(3, 148) < 400): 
        print line.rstrip()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I just edited your post, plus I indented the `print line` as it wouldn't be correct otherwise

Comment: *but it doesnt work.* please be more specific. We cannot help if we don't know what's wrong

Comment: I think you misunderstand the usage of `fp.seek` it doesn't return a value, plus even if it did you are comparing either a string or raw bytes to an int which is not going to work

Answer (score 2):

To compare a number with a string you need to convert it:

`int(fp.seek(3, 148)) < 400`

You have to check the string to contain only numbers.

But `seek()` is not the function you are looking for, you can use it to skip the bytes of a file to a specific point.

Look here: [seek() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696472/seek-function)

If your number is always on the same position you can use:

`int(line[148:150]) < 400`

Try it with regular expressions and string operations:

http://pymotw.com/2/re/