# Python writing to .txt alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

Need help cant write to file alphabetically

```
class_name = "class 1.txt"    #adds '.txt' to the end of the file so it can be used to create a file under the name a user specifies
with open(class_name , 'r+') as file:
    name = (name)
    file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
    file.write(str(score))
    file.write('\n')
    lineList = file.readlines()
    for line in sorted(lineList):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: what is name and score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should overwrite the file with the new (alphabetized) data. This is MASSIVELY easier than trying to track `file.seek` calls (which are measured in bytes, not lines or even characters!) and not significantly less performant.

```
with open(class_name, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines.append("{name} : {score}\n".format(name=name, score=score))

with open(class_name, "w") as f:  # re-opening as "w" will blank the file
    for line in sorted(lines):
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need calls of `file.seek` to set the read/write position accordingly.

See [seek() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696472/seek-function) for some explanations.