# Writing string to S3 with boto3: "'dict' object has no attribute 'put'"

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

In an AWS lambda, I am using boto3 to put a string into an S3 file:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
data = s3.get_object(Bucket=XXX, Key=YYY)
data.put('Body', 'hello')
```

I am told this:

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'put'
```

The same happens with `data.put('hello')` which is the method recommended by the top answers at [How to write a file or data to an S3 object using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3) and with `data.put_object`: `'dict' object has no attribute 'put_object'`.

What am I doing wrong?

On the opposite, reading works great (with `data.get('Body').read().decode('utf-8')`).

Comment: I find the easiest way to use S3 is to create a file locally, then upload it via `put_object()`. That way, you are separating the 'file creation' from the 'file uploading', which makes things easier to debug.

Answer (score 11):

`put_object` is a method of the `s3` object, not the data object.

Here is a full working example with Python 3.7:

```
import json
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket = 'mybucket'
    key = 'id.txt'
    id = None

    # Write id to S3
    s3.put_object(Body='Hello!', Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    # Read id from S3
    data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    id = data.get('Body').read().decode('utf-8') 
    logger.info("Id:" + id)


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Id:' + id)
    }
```