# How to write all logs of django console to to custome file file?

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

I just Started to try django logging module in my project...

I am following django docs for loging all logs from  Django’s default logging configuration to a custome log file. 
I copied the [following code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#examples) to my settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/project/debug.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

Here I assume that all of my console logs must be written in `debug.log` file,
But its not happening.
Can anyone please suggest me whata wrong here or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Does the directory `/project/` exist and has proper rights to write from the user you start your project?

Comment: @phoenix I think it exists correctly, because when file path was wrong It was giving me an Error of file not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the filename, You need to set it to the right path!

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'APPNAME.log'),
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

Comment: I think it that's not case, because when file path was wrong It was giving me an Error of file not found?

Comment: What did you name your .log file?

Comment: Is there anyway to change filename as file in s3 bucket?

Comment: Of course, you can replace the value of the key "filename" to a call back function and that function can do all of your authentication and file writing.

Something like "filename" : def store_s3() { #logic} 

then follow this guide question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3

Answer (score 2):

Replace with a static route and do not forget to give the file permission.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/home/user/proyect/debug.log,
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you have no logs for `django` handler.
Define one with empty string as a default one:

```
...
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
...
```

The 'django' logger is used in django only once - in the library itself.
When creating a logger you give it a name - usually something like this: `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` - where a name is the name of the module which it will be used in.
You can specify and configure different modules to write/report in a different way.