# Is there a way to save the JSON output of a function to S3 using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have written a function in Python to analyse documents and retrieve key-value pairs from forms in these documents. Below is just the handler bit of it.

```
def handler(event, context):
  bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
  key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

  try:
      document = TTFunction(bucket,key)
      KVpairs=[]
      for page in document.pages:
        KVpairs= output(page)
```

When I print the output of this function, it is in JSON. Is there a way to save this output as a JSON or a CSV in the same bucket?

Comment: Yes. See boto3 lib about  writing data to bucket. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html?id=docs_gateway

Comment: Alright, but I have tried both put_object and upload_file and I couldn't get the function to save. Do I need to save the file first in a temp directory or can I do that directly?

Comment: No need to save anything

Comment: Okay, I'd really appreciate any suggestions on this. I am really new to all of this. I was able to do that in my local drive but not on S3.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a file or data to an S3 object using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3)

Comment: This will help you understand boto3 https://realpython.com/python-boto3-aws-s3/

Answer (score 0):

- This is just a sample code[aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-put_object.py.html)
- boto3 docs for [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) note the body can be bytes or file.
- You lambda must have WRITE permissions on a bucket to add an object to it.

```
    # Put the object
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        s3.put_object(Bucket=dest_bucket_name, Key=dest_object_name, Body=object_data)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the code for that. One of the problems I had was converting the body to Bytes, but I found a way. I will post the code soon.

Comment: when you are going to do that?