# Writing a list of dictionaries directly to S3 as csv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I have a list of dictionaries like 
`temp_dict = [{'id':'1', 'name':'john'},{'id':'2', 'name':'jake'},{'id':'3', 'name':'jacob'}]` 
Is there a way using which I can directly write this dictionary as a csv file (pipe delimited) onto S3. I do not want to create a csv file on my local from this list and then copy that to S3.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be helpful:

```
import csv

class Pipe:
    value = ""
    def write(self, text):
        self.value = self.value + text

temp_dict = [{'id':'1', 'name':'john'},{'id':'2', 'name':'jake'},{'id':'3', 'name':'jacob'}]

pipe = Pipe()
writer = csv.DictWriter(pipe, temp_dict[0].keys())
for entry in temp_dict:
    writer.writerow(entry)

print(pipe.value)
```

```
1,john
2,jake
3,jacob
```

Basically, we write a class to imitate a file object in write mode, then we create an instance, and pass it to the `DictWriter`. At the end, we get the csv text from `pipe.value`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution which is a little bit more elegant and very fast particularly with large lists of dictionaries.

```
import io
import csv

data = [{"param1": 1, "param2": 2}, {"param1": 1, "param2": 3}]

stream = io.StringIO()
headers = list(data[0].keys())
writer = csv.DictWriter(stream, fieldnames=headers)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(data)

csv_string_object = stream.getvalue()
```

Using this string object which is a representation of your CSV file content, you can directly insert it into S3 in whichever manner you prefer via boto3.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=<your_profile_name>)
resource = session.resource("s3")
resource.Object(<s3_bucket>, <s3_key>).put(Body=csv_string_object)
```

Beware, your CSV file is now loaded in memory and might crash with large quantities of data.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I am pretty sure it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your issue.

Convert your in-memory object in to binary stream and pass onto s3 using boto3.

[How to write a file or data to an S3 object using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3)

Comment: Hi Gauri, can you please share some sample code. I am not sure how to convert list of dictionaries into a csv stream