# How to upload a file from a Flask's HTML form to an S3 bucket using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an HTML form (implemented in Flask) for uploading files. And I want to store the uploaded files directly to S3.

The relevant part of the Flask implementation is as follows:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return '<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="files" /><button>Upload</button></form>'
```

I then use `boto3` to upload the file to S3 as follows:

```
file = request.files['files']
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
     aws_access_key_id='******',
     aws_secret_access_key='*******')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('MY_BUCKET_NAME')

bucket.Object(file.filename).put(Body=file)
```

`file` is a `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` object.

But I get the following error when uploading the file to S3:

> `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (BadDigest) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received`.

How can I upload the file to S3?

Comment: `request.files['files']` is returning file storage like this `<FileStorage: 'FRIDAY_SALE_50_14.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Flask web framework, the `file` variable is of type [werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).

I think the problem is that the [`put()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put) method expects a byte sequence or a file-like object as its `Body` argument. So, it does not know what to do with the Flask's `FileStorage` object.

A possible solution could be to use `file.read()` to get a sequence of bytes and then pass it to `put()`:

```
bucket.Object(file.filename).put(Body=file.read())
```

Comment: Yuppp!!! its working. Now file is getting stored in to S3 bucket. but when I open that its blank.... image is not appearing, it seems like file not written properly. and its size is showing `0B`

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3

Comment: @SaurabhSharma where you able to solve this issue, i am facing the same situation. In my case the size of image is altered as i am not able to read the content of file storage object properly.

Comment: Hi @Utkarsh, Make sure you add `fileObj.seek(0)` before uploading file into S3

`filename = secure_filename(fileObj.filename)
        key_path = os.path.join(filePath,filename)
        s3_resource = boto3.resource(
                's3',
                aws_access_key_id=app.config['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
                aws_secret_access_key=app.config['S3_SECRET_KEY']
        )
        bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucket-name')
        fileObj.seek(0)
        bucket.upload_fileobj(fileObj, Key=key_path)`

Comment: @SaurabhSharma the image is of type filestorage and when we do f.read() we are reading the image content along with the metadata, so when the image is getting stored in the S3 bucket the size of image is not matching the actual size.

Comment: as @SaurabhSharma metioned, we should  set`file.seek(0)` before `put_object()`.