# Uploading image on AWS S3 using boto is having the size: 0 byte, Python, Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload the image to my bucket on AWS S3. Earlier it was working fine. But now the uploaded image is having the size 0 byte. I have tried rolling back to previous versions of my project on GitHub. But nothing seems to work now. I am stuck on this issue for 2 days now.

```
def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket_name, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=BaseConfig.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=BaseConfig.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    s3.upload_fileobj(local_file, bucket_name, s3_file)
    file_url = '%s/%s/%s' % (s3.meta.endpoint_url, bucket_name, s3_file)
    return file_url
```

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('image', 
  type=FileStorage,
  required=True, 
  help='image is required',
  location='files'
)

class Classifier(Resource):
  def post(self):
    data = Classifier.parser.parse_args()
    image = data["image"]
    key_name = "some-key-name"
    upload_to_aws(image, BaseConfig.BUCKET_NAME, key_name)
    return {message: "uploaded successfully"}, 200
```

Comment: What is `data["image"]`?

Comment: It is an image received from the request, it has the property name "image".

Comment: You mean actual image data or just a file name?

Comment: actual image data

Comment: You can try: `image = io.BytesIO(data["image"])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232910/discussion-between-zuhaib-khan-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1):

The `upload_fileobj()` function will [upload a file-like object to S3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj). You would pass it a `file` object returned from an `open()` command.

If the `image` variable contains a filename, you should be using `upload_file()` instead.

Comment: My image variable contains the file and I have tried open()  command. It show the following error. TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage.

Comment: In that case, you would use `put_object(Body=image)`.

Comment: using put_object(Body=image) shows the exact same error, as the one in the first comment.

Comment: `FileStorage` apparently has something to do with Flask? Whatever it is, it is not the "actual image data".

Comment: Yes, I'm using flask-restful. Is there any way I could convert this file, and upload it then? It was working fine earlier. I don't know what is going on now.

Comment: This might help: [How to upload a file from a Flask's HTML form to an S3 bucket using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239208/174777) It's using a slightly different way of using boto3, but the equivalent in your code would be `s3.put_object(...,Body=image.read())`. See if that works!