# saving from api to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the below python code to save the csv from an api to an amazon s3 bucket using bot03 and python, but I can't see where I'm going wrong.  When I execute the code I don't get any error but the file never appear in the s3 bucket.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

file_name = "test.csv"
bucket = "mybucket"

def main():
    url = "https://api0.solar.sheffield.ac.uk/pvlive/v3/pes/10?start=2021-01-01T00:00:00&end=2021-07-06T00:00:00&data_format=csv"
    x = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',})

    s3 = bot03.client("s3")
    with open("test.csv","rb") as file2:
     s3.upload_fileobj(x.content, bucket, "test.cvc")
```

any tips/advice would be appreciated.  I'm a python/aws newbie so apologies if a basic question

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to acheive what I need

```
file_name = "test.csv"
bucket = "my_bucket"

def main():
    url = "https://api0.solar.sheffield.ac.uk/pvlive/v3/pes/10?start=2021-01-01T00:00:00&end=2021-07-06T00:00:00&data_format=csv"
    x = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',})



    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'snowflake/csv/df1.csv').put(Body=x.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for persisting with this and for putting the answer. You have saved me just in time for a presentation!

Comment: In case anyone else comes looking, the answer to this also has some useful code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3

Answer (score -1):

per the OP(Original Post),
did you try

(line 11)  s3 = boto3.client("s3")  -- OP: bot03.client("s3")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33317927)