# AWS lambda "errorMessage": "cannot import name 'resolve_checksum_context' from 'botocore.client' (/var/runtime/botocore/client.py)"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda function to analyse a stock price and to upload the findings as a .csv file into my s3 bucket. And in order to do that, I'm using `s3fs`. but I'm unable to import s3fs to my lambda function. The error message is

```
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot import name 'resolve_checksum_context' from 'botocore.client' (/var/runtime/botocore/client.py)",
  "errorType": "ImportError",
  "requestId": "314d356c-c114-4c97-84a2-deb388f6cf8a",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    import s3fs\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/packages/s3fs/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/packages/s3fs/core.py\", line 20, in <module>\n    import aiobotocore.session\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/packages/aiobotocore/session.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    from .client import AioClientCreator, AioBaseClient\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/packages/aiobotocore/client.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    from botocore.client import logger, PaginatorDocstring, ClientCreator, \\\n"
  ]
}
```

What have I done so far?

1. Used lambda layer to load `s3fs` package.

zipped the required `s3fs` package file and upload it as a layer (the same package had no error while I imported it to my virtual environment on my local machine). The error message was the same as above

the zipped file had the file structure mentioned by the AWS documentation. [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path)

I even tried

```
sys.path.append('/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages')

import s3fs
```

`/opt` is where the files uploaded as layers would be present

2. Mounted an EFS file system with the required files to my lambda function

Used EC instance to download all the packages into my EFS file system (This included all the other pip packages including boto3, NumPy, pandas etc). Those other packages I mention had no hiccups in being loaded into my lambda function.

```
sys.path.append("/mnt/packages")

import s3fs
```

`/mnt/packages` is the local mount path of my EFS file system in lambda function.

```
Name: s3fs
Version: 0.4.2
```

Both the above methods showed the same error.

The same version of the package had no issues in my local machine, Virtual environment and in Docker Build. The error seems to be only in my AWS lambda function.

Since the ultimate goal is to read the .cvs file from the S3 and update the findings and re-upload the same file back. So, I would also be fine with knowing any other methods which would circumvent the use of s3fs.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Install s3fs to access S3",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "aee2b9a8-699e-43eb-949a-2c0e427696aa",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

***EDIT: I was able to upload using boto3. The solution can be found here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3). But yeah, when using s3fs it did not work.***

Comment: Facing the same error. I was using python 3.7.x. Hence, went ahead with 3.6.x for now and the code worked. However, would appreciate somebody helping out on this!

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem, I've been able to solve it by using `s3fs==2021.10.0`. It involves some big version changes in other dependencies so maybe one of them is causing the problem. This is the output of poetry when asking changing the version. I assume the botocore or aiobotocore versions are the ones causing the problem.

```
  • Updating jmespath (1.0.0 -> 0.10.0)
  • Updating botocore (1.24.21 -> 1.20.106)
  • Updating s3transfer (0.5.2 -> 0.4.2)
  • Updating boto3 (1.21.21 -> 1.17.106)
  • Updating aiobotocore (2.3.2 -> 1.4.2)
  • Updating fsspec (2022.5.0 -> 2021.10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the problem for me was aiobotocore version.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33698624)