# Python file.read using more RAM than file size

Tags: python, file, text, ram

I am having some issues with the below code:

```
with open(".../file.txt", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

I have a particular `txt` file of size 2.5GB and am trying to read it into my 16GB of RAM. However, after only a second or two, Python seems to be using 100% of my RAM and I get a memory error. The exact same code works as intended for other files. What can I do to investigate this?

**EDIT**

Actually, it appears as if Windows is lying about its file size... The file's proprties tab indicates 2.5GB but when loading it into the WordPad text editor, it was also progressively reading data into memory and beyonf the size indicated by Windows. Any thoughts?

Comment: SO already has a few answers on how to "chunk" files when opening them, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201013/read-a-file-in-byte-chunks-using-python)

Comment: So should I expect to use 6x-8x more RAM than the file size? is Python innefficient at reading these large files? Thanks for the links.

Comment: I wouldn't know, but that doesn't sound correct. That's a _lot_ of overhead.

Comment: I am going to "chunk" anyway as its reliable and good practice. I am still curious about my issue though.