# How can I read last 10 bytes from a text file?

Tags: python

```
Welcome to demofile.txt
This file is for testing purposes.
Good Luck!
```

Above Content Is In My Text File

How to read last 10 bytes from that text file? The expected output is:

```
Good Luck!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [seek() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696472/seek-function)

Comment: yeah it helped me @user5126

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
in_file.seek(-10, 2)  # where 2 denotes the reference point being the end of the file
```

So then:

```
in_file = open("demofile.txt", "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
in_file.seek(-10, 2)
s = in_file.read(10)
print(s)
```

OUTPUT:

```
b'Good Luck!'
```

Comment: **Last** 10 bytes!

Comment: @KenY-N Edited for it.