# Why isn't this Python code copying the text in one file to another?

Tags: python, io, text-files

So,I am attempting to copy some text from one .txt file to another. However,when I open the second .txt file,the lines have not been written there by the program. This is the code that I'm using.

```
chptfile = open('v1.txt',"a+",encoding="utf-8")
chptfile.truncate(0)
chptfile.write("nee\n")
chptfile.write("een")

lines = chptfile.readlines()
chptv2 = open ('v2.txt',"a+",encoding="utf-8")
for line in lines:
    chptv2.write(line)

chptv2.close()
chptfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file pointer of `chptfile` is at the end of the file after you perform the writes, so you should call the `seek` method to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file before you can read its content:

```
chptfile = open('v1.txt',"a+",encoding="utf-8")
chptfile.truncate(0)
chptfile.write("nee\n")
chptfile.write("een")
chptfile.seek(0)
lines = chptfile.readlines()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in blhsing's answer, you need to call the [`seek()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696554/13552470) method. However, there is also a bad practice in you code. Instead of opening and closing a file, use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
with open('v1.txt',"a+",encoding="utf-8") as chptfile:
    chptfile.truncate(0)
    chptfile.write("nee\n")
    chptfile.write("een")
    chptfile.seek(0)
    lines = chptfile.readlines()

with open ('v2.txt',"a+",encoding="utf-8") as chptv2:
    chptv2.write(''.join(line))
```